# Relocate git branch into another branch

Tags: git, version-control

Assuming:

- C = Commit
- B-Name = Branch-Name
- R = Rebase

Currently I have a branch like this:

```
--(C1)                    :B-Master
     \--(C2)--(C3)        :B-Feature1
     \--(C4)--(C5)        :B-Feature2
     \--(C6)--(C7)        :B-Feature3
```

**How do I rebase into something like this:**

```
---(C1)-------------(R1)----------------(R2)            :B-Master
     \--(C2)--(C3)--/ \                /                :B-Feature1
                       \--(C4)--(C5)--/                 :B-Feature2
     \--(C6)--(C7)                                      :B-Feature3
```

Explanation:

Currently in my Master branch there's a last commit of C1. And at C1 I have multiple different idea coming regarding different feature. I start to code each of them on different branch. When each of the feature completed.

Example: When Feature1 branch complete, I want to rebase the Feature2 branch into R1. Meaning the Feature2 branch has all code of Feature1 code before C4 even exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing commit `C4` cannot be changed *in any way at all* and that includes the fact that its parent is commit `C1`.  So you can't get what you want, but you can probably get what you need (as the Rolling Stones song goes): a new `C4'` (`C8`?) that is a lot *like* `C4` but attaches to `R1`.

I prefer single-letter names for commits, and would draw the original this way:

```
...--B   <-- master
     |\
     | C--D   <-- feature1
     |\
     | E--F   <-- feature2
      \
       G--H   <-- feature3
```

We'll end up with, e.g.:

```
...--B------I------J   <-- master
     |\    / \    /
     | C--D   E'-F'   <-- feature2
      \    `......    <-- feature1
       G--H           <-- feature3
```

where commit `I` is a (forced) merge commit made to merge `feature1` into `master` without doing a fast-forward, `E'-F'` are the copies of `E-F` altered to come after `I`, `J` is another forced merge, and `G-H` are untouched as they still spring from commit `B`:

```
git switch master
git merge --no-ff feature1
git switch feature2
git rebase master
git switch master
git merge --no-ff feature2
```

If you don't need to force merge commits `I` and `J` to exist, see [Bogdan Onischenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73146753/1256452).

Answer (score 2):

```
git switch B-Feature2
git rebase B-Feature1
```

You will get:

```
--(C1)                                   :B-Master
     \--(C2)--(C3)-\                     :B-Feature1
                    \--(C4)--(C5)        :B-Feature2
     \--(C6)--(C7)                       :B-Feature3
```